# How to stop AdWords campaign via Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I have MCC account which i'm using to administrate couple AdWords accounts.
I wrote Script which checking base budget of each account and then weekly check how many did they spend. Then the script subtracts these values and then every data is saved into Google Drive (spreadsheet).

Main idea behind this script was to track current budget and then warn me when some account have no more money. But then I figured out that actually i do not need to track it because AdWords script already have functions which gives possibility to stop campaign.

So i digged little bit but everything i tried is not working.
Here is extracted function (example) with i using:

```
function main() {

  var Customer = GetAccountData("XXX-XXX-XXXX");

  StopCampaigns(Customer);

  if(isCampaignRuning(Customer)){
    Logger.log("Campaign is runing !");
  }else{
    Logger.log("Campaign is STOPPED!");
  }

}

/*Helper functions */

function isCampaignRuning(account){
  MccApp.select(account);
  var campaigns = AdWordsApp.campaigns().get();
  var IsCampaignRuning = false;
  while(campaigns.hasNext()) {
    var campaign = campaigns.next();
    if(!campaign.isPaused()){
      IsCampaignRuning=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return IsCampaignRuning;
}

function StopCampaigns(account){
  MccApp.select(account);
  var campaigns = AdWordsApp.campaigns().get();
  while(campaigns.hasNext()) {
    var campaign = campaigns.next();
    if(!campaign.isPaused()){
      campaign.pause();
    }
  }
}

function GetAccountData(id){
  var childAccounts = MccApp.accounts().withIds([id]).get();
  if(!childAccounts.hasNext()){
    return false;
  }
  var childAccount = childAccounts.next();
  return childAccount;
}
```

Here is what's happening in console:

```
13:08:20.974    Campaign is runing !
```

In changes tab:

```
Change for: (Here is campaign name)
New value (if run now): temporarily suspended
type of change: Update > Status
Current value: Active
```

How can i correctly pause campaign ?
Is there better way to track current budget of accounts ?

Comment: So I find this completely confusing, but Adwords script and Google Apps script are similar but different tools.  You need to ask this to the Adwords script community.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who will look for answer to the same problem.
There was no problem in script itself.
"if run now" - should speak itself. I was using "Preview" to run script.
In that "preview" mode script doesn't change anything in account and campaign.
It just needed to be "run" normally.